# Query by Date Range for a column field in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to query a database with Sequelize to get items that were created between a certain date range. I used the `$between` operator but I don't seem to be getting anything.

`{ where: {"createdAt":{"$between":["2018-03-31T21:00:00.000Z","2018-05-30T05:23:59.007Z"]}} }`

Can anyone help with how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I also had the same problem, I was getting empty array in response. The problem got fixed using :

```
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
```

and then using `[Op.between]` as shown below:

```
where: {
  createdAt: {
    [Op.between]: ["2018-07-08T14:06:48.000Z", "2019-10-08T22:33:54.000Z"]
  }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: ahhh I looking for something like select * FROM table where "2021-04-13" BETWEEN start_date_column and end_date_column any idea?

Answer (score 7):

`$between` syntax seems to be right. There are no issues with the way you used. I tried to replicate with the following query

```
  model.findAll({
    where: {
      created_at: { 
        "$between": ["2018-03-31T21:00:00.000Z","2018-05-30T05:23:59.007Z"]
      }
    }
  })
```

The only change is, I use `created_at` instead of `createdAt`. Make sure that your column name is right. If it is not, it should have thrown `SequelizeDatabaseError`. Look for it.

If everything else is right, then you might not be having data in that date range :)

Comment: Thanks. It's funny it's not working on my end. I've tried a larger date range and I keep getting an empty value. I'll go through my code again.

Comment: Ideally you should also be using the symbol based operators like [Op.between]: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators (it's better from a security perspective)